# Why can't I display this string on MessageBox?

Tags: c++, windows, printf, messagebox

I've created a pointer pointing to a couple of chars but after assigning it to some value and then trying to print it on the MessageBox and compiling it is giving me some errors.My code is given below:

```
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void main()
 {

  char buff[100];
  string id = "ST_5";
  sprintf_s(buff, "id: %s", id.c_str());


   MessageBox(NULL, buff,L"User-id", MB_OK);

 }
```

Please help me in finding the problem in this code, Thanks.

My compiler's output:
c:\users\zafri\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test3\test3\test3.cpp(19): error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [100]' to 'LPCWSTR'
          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: "some errors"? Have you read it?

Comment: @zafri, it was not me. But since you showed us your error message, it is much simplier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the compiler error messages.

The second and third arguments to `MessageBox` have to have the same type. Either you call `MessageBoxA` with two `char *`, or you call `MessageBoxW` with two `wchar_t *`.

One fix for your code would be to do `MessageBoxA(NULL, buff, "User-id", MB_OK)`.

You are using `sprintf_s` incorrectly too, please read its documentation. IMHO it would be better to use the standard function `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, "%s", id.c_str());
```

Note that you could do away with `buff` entirely and write:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, id.c_str(), "User-id", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use wchar_t type for all variables, objects and functions, this code works:

```
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

  wchar_t buff[100];
  wstring id = L"ST_5";
  swprintf_s(buff, 100, L"id: %s", id.c_str());
  MessageBoxW(NULL, buff,L"User-id", MB_OK);

 }
```

The function swprintf_s() is the wchar_t/safe version of the sprintf/snprintf

Ciao

Answer (score 1):

For the second argument of `MessageBox` you use `char`s, while for the third one you use `wchar_t`s. This is wrong. If you build not for UNICODE, remove `L` from `L"User-id"` so it becomes `char` array.