# Display a Variable in MessageBoxW c++

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, messagebox

I have a proplem , like :

Ex : 
    MessageBoxW(0,L"Đây là ABC (This is ABC)",L"Lỗi (Error)",0);

All ok !
But i want to replace ABC to variable , like it :
    char buff[500];
    char author[] = "ABC";
    sprintf_s(buff,"Đây là %s (This is %s)",author);
    MessageBoxW(0, WHAT WILL BE HERE,L"Lỗi (Error)",0);

I hope someone may help !

Comment: `MessageBoxW` requires a wide string.

Comment: Take a look at the CString class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043%28v=vs.60%29.aspx. It allows you to format the string with the format memberfunction and supports LPCTSTR to pass to the messagebox

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly display a variable, but it has to be of the correct type. MessageBoxW takes a `LPCWSTR` (wide), and a `char[]` provides a `LPCSTR` (narrow) instead. So swap out the types accordingly:

```
WCHAR buff[500];                                      // WCHAR not char
WCHAR author[] = L"ABC";                              // WCHAR not char
swprintf_s(buff, L"Đây là %s (This is %s)", author);  // swprintf_s not sprintf_s
MessageBoxW(0, buff, L"Lỗi (Error)", 0);
```

It's also a good idea to avoid the raw buffers and use a wrapper class such as `ATL::CStringW` or `std::wstring`.

---

<sup>(I had some trouble deciding whether to answer this. The related question [Why can't I display this string on MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381450/why-cant-i-display-this-string-on-messagebox) seems like a duplicate, but it's closed as a duplicate of [Cannot convert parameter from 'const char[20]' to 'LPCWSTR'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481378/error-c2664-messageboxw-cannot-convert-parameter-2-from-const-char-20-t) which does not answer this question. In fact its answer is included in this question.)</sup>